# How to find a function that fits a given data set?

Tags: breadth-first-search

The search algorithm is a Breadth first search. I'm not sure how to store terms from and equation into a open list. The function f(x) has the form of ax^e1 + bx^e2 + cx^e3 + k, where a, b, c, are coefficients; k is constant. All exponents, coefficients, and constants are integers between 0 and 5.

Initial state: of the problem solving process should be any term from the ax^e1, bx^e2, cX^e3, k.

The algorithm gradually expands the number of terms in each level of the list.
Not sure how to add the terms to an equation from an open Queue. That is the question.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem that you are dealing belongs to the **regression analysis** area, and several techniques are available to find a function that fits a given data set, including the popular least squares methods for finding the line of best fit given a dataset (a brief starting point is the [related page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), but if you want to deepen this topic, you should look at the research paper out there).

If you want to stick with the breadth first search algorithm, although this kind of approach is not common for such a problem, first of all, you need to define all the elements for a search problem, namely (see for more information Chapter 3 of the book of Stuart and Russell, [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)):

- Initial state: Some initial values for the different terms.
- Actions: in your case it should be a change in the different terms. Note that you should discretize the changes in the values.
- Transition function: function that determines the new states given a state and an action.
- Goal test: a check to recognize whether a state is a goal state or not, and so to terminate the search. There are different ways to define this test in a regression problem. One way is to set a threshold for the sum of the square errors.
- Step cost: The cost for an action. In such an abstract problem, probably you can consider the unweighted distance from the initial state on the search graph.

Note that you should carefully think about these elements, as, for example, they determine how efficient your search would be or whether you will have cycles in the search graph.

After you defined all of the elements for the search problem, you basically have to implement:

- Node, that contains information about the parent, the state, and the current cost;
- Function to expand a given node that returns the successor nodes (according to the transition function, the actions, and the step cost);
- Goal test;
- The actual search algorithm. In the queue at the beginning you will have the node containing the initial state. After, it is updated with the successor nodes.